# How can I include this inside jQuery instead of inside body tag?

Tags: jquery

```
<body onload="onDocLoad()" onresize="onResize()">
```

I would like my webpage and JavaScript to do the same thing,

but I want to include those function calls inside jQuery source.

Is it

```
$( document ).ready( onDocLoad ).resize(onResize);
```

Thanks a lot, Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close. An exact replacement would be:

```
$(window).on("load", onDocLoad).on("resize", onResize);
```

That waits for the window `load` event before the first call to `onDocLoad`

You may be able to do this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    onDocLoad();
    $(window).on("resize", onResize); 
});
```

Or even this, with the `script` tag at the **end** of the document (just before the closing `</body>` tag):

```
(function() {
    onDocLoad();
    $(window).on("resize", onResize); 
})();
```

It depends on whether you need to wait for all resources to load before the first call to `onDocLoad`. If you do, use the first example above (which waits for the `window` `load` event). If you don't, either of the second examples makes the first call to `onDocLoad` sooner, before images and other resources have finished loading.

Comment: Why enclose the last option in an IIFE?  It doesn't appear to have any use.

Comment: @jfriend00: Just my standard practice. Usually you end up with a variable getting added at some point, which I don't want to become global... (I left off my usual `"use strict";` so as to avoid getting *too* off-topic.)